# Popups are slow on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qml, qt6

I am currently in the process of porting an application from Linux to Windows. The performance is great on Linux, but I realized that switching between pages (so, loading new pages) of my application is quite slow on windows.
I have used the Qml Profiler to check what is going on, and I saw that by far the most time is spent rendering Popups on these pages, that are not opened.
For some reason, it seems like they are directly rendered when opening the page, even though they are not opened.

I wouldn't be sure what code to provide, since it happens for literally every popup. They all start as follows:

```
Popup
{
    id: root
    // Set width and height

    background: Rectangle { radius: 6; color: Style.colorPopupBackground }
    modal: true
    Overlay.modal: Rectangle { color: Style.colorPopupDim; opacity: 1 }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling the pop up until you want it?

Comment: What do you mean with "disabling" @mzimmers? I thought (as it is on linux) that popups are not rendered until opened

Comment: Do you mean making the `enabled` property `false` by default and toggling it `onOpened` and `onClosed`?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, but I was just speculating. I like the answer that Jurgen Lutz gave better.

Comment: If the `enabling: visible` works, I think it is the best approach.

Comment: @SMR it sadly doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Loader` to pospone the creation of the `Popups`. Something like this:

```
Loader {
    id: dialog
    active: false
    sourceComponent: component

    Component {
        id: component

        Popup
        {
            id: root
            // Set width and height

            background: Rectangle { radius: 6; color: Style.colorPopupBackground }
            modal: true
            Overlay.modal: Rectangle { color: Style.colorPopupDim; opacity: 1 }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Than you can call `dialog.active = true` to create and show your popup.

Comment: Is that the best approach? Its very inconvenient since I have dozens of popups and it works as it should on Linux

Comment: I would say this is the cleanest approach. Currently it does not really work on Linux, your Linux PC has just more power and you do not notice the creation overhead ;) You could write your own Popup with the loading handling and reuse it.